# Does an 'external product code' field exist in Prestashop?

Tags: database, prestashop

I'm exporting products data from our enterprise Erp to a Prestashop installation.

Our ERP products code are alphanumerics like `A001`, `A002`, etc. I would like to use this code into Prestashop, but if I'm not wrong, Prestashop Id is numerical.

So, does a field like "*External Product Code*" exist that I can use in the Products table in Prestashop?

Answer (score 1):

While Prestashop does use a unique numerical autonumber to identify products (`ps_product.id_product`), there are also three fields into which you could provide external references - Reference Code, EAN-13 or JAN Barcode, and UPC Barcode, though it is apparent the Reference Code field (`ps_product.reference`) would be the most appropriate and does not have any validation other than to limit the acceptable characters to alphanumerics and special characters `.-_#\`.

Since this question was asked some time ago I'm not sure which version of Prestahop @stighy would have had installed and be referring to, however having checked I can confirm that this reference field was present in v1.4.11.0 and is still present in v1.6.0.14.